# XCode: Run script after application unitest to copy files from device

Tags: ios, xcode, run-script, octest

I run an application test from XCode on my device. 
The test creates some files on the device.
After the tests has finihsed i would like to copy these file from the device to my machine.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?
I am using XCode 4.6.2

thanks
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files are created in the Documents directory, you can use iTunes file sharing to get the files.

[Here's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app) a tutorial

**EDIT based on comment**

Not sure if this fits your use case - you could try integration with the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync). Your app, once the files are created, can sync the files in a Dropbox folder. You can have the Windows/Mac app installed to have the files synced to your computer as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not quite what I am looking for. With iTunes file sharing I still have to use a tool and manual actions to copy my files. Right now I use  [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com) to do this. What I am looking for is an automated solution.

Comment: Thanks again for your input. This still sounds way too complicated. All I want to to is automatically copy some files, integrating a whole framework that I would use only when running my tests is a bit too much.